# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when running integration test

Tags: testing, gradle, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I am having a very basic straightforward configuration as follow

```
    --- clip ---

    compile group: 'org.jboss.arquillian', name: 'arquillian-bom', version: '1.4.0.Final', ext: 'pom'
    testCompile group: 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit', name: 'arquillian-junit-container', version: '1.4.0.Final'
    testCompile group: 'org.jboss.arquillian.container', name: 'arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    testCompile 'org.jboss.weld:weld-core:2.4.5.Final'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
--- end clip ---
```

And this is my Test class

```
    @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TooltipGeneratorTest {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClass(XXXX.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }


    @Test
    public void testStart() {
        System.out.print("gamma");
        assert true;
    }
```

AS you see, I am not even injecting a bean inside. I am unable to run a basic arquillian test in weld-ee container.

The error I am having when running with

```
gradle clean test
```

is

```
<failure message="java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getAnnotatedFields()Ljava/util/List;" type="java.lang.NoSuchMethodError">java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

Is there any missing dependency? 
As mentioned in the [tutorial](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/?utm_source=cta), I have all the needed dependencies

1. Arquillian JUnit integration
2. Arquillian container adapter for the target container
3. Container runtime (for an embedded container)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getAnnotatedFields()Ljava/util/List;

and

> testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

---

The method `List<FrameworkField> TestClass.getAnnotatedFields` does exist in JUnit 4, but that specific version with [no arguments](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/model/TestClass.html#getAnnotatedFields())  that Arquillian is looking for was only added in JUnit **4.12**.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching I found the solution:

***Context***
arquillian works perfectly with maven when this is imported

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

***problem***
writing

```
compile group: 'org.jboss.arquillian', name: 'arquillian-bom', version: '1.4.0.Final', ext: 'pom'
```

will not replace it as gradle does not import the pom artifact with scope import

***solution***
Fortunately, gradle new version 4.6 and up support this features. so

1. use gradle 4.6 and up
2. add this to gradle.settings (for bom support)

   enableFeaturePreview('IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT')

***Full Solution***

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
//    compileOnly 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    testCompile 'org.jboss.weld:weld-core:2.4.5.Final'


    // this is the BOM
    testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.4.0.Final'
    testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.4.0.Final'
    testCompile group: 'org.arquillian.container', name: 'arquillian-container-chameleon', version: '1.0.0.CR2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

and under

src/test/resources/

the file arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <container qualifier="wildfly" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="chameleonTarget">wildfly:11.0.0.Final:managed</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```